# Change error message with Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Simply, I have a Shiny app, where users can select various combinations of values in a data set and produces a graph. However for some of those combinations there is no data and Shiny produces an error message:

`Error: 'from' must be length 1`

How can I replace this error message with a more informative message, like:

`Sorry, there is no data for you requested combination. Please change your input selections`

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using the `validate` and `need` functions. The code would look something like this:

```
output$MyPlot<-renderPlot({
  validate(
     need(MyData(), "Sorry, there is no data for you requested combination. 
                      Please change your input selections"
     )
   )
   ...code for making plot...
})
```

If the `MyData()` part does not exist due to giving an error, than the message will display, otherwise the plot will. Check `?validate` for all the details.